# How to multiply two arrays of different length?

Tags: php, arrays, math, multiplication

I have two arrays of different length:

```
$a = array(10, 20, 30, 40, 50);
$b = array(1, 2, 3);
```

I'd like to multiply them (e.g. `$c=array_mult($a, $b)`) in the way, that the shorter array is repeated. `$c` should be `10, 40, 90, 40, 100` since:

```
10 * 1 = 10
20 * 2 = 40
30 * 3 = 90

40 * 1 = 40
50 * 2 = 100
```

Is there a built-in function in PHP to fulfill this task? How can I solve this problem efficiently?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a built-in function to do that. You can do it with a `foreach` and the modulo operator pretty easily, though:

```
$c = array();
$len = count($b);
foreach($a as $key => $value){
    $c[$key] = $value*$b[($key % $len)];
}
```

Comment: `$b` may not always be the smaller array.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `for` loop with modulus operator (`%`):

```
$a = array(10, 20, 30, 40, 50);
$b = array(1, 2, 3);

$aCount = count($a);
$bCount = count($b);

for ($i=0; $i < $aCount; $i++) { 
    $result[] = $b[$i % $bCount] * $a[$i];
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 10
    [1] => 40
    [2] => 90
    [3] => 40
    [4] => 100
)
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/139371)

---

**UPDATE:** If you'd like to have the shorter array repeated regardless of their order of length, you can use the following solution:

```
$a = array(10, 20);
$b = array(1, 2, 3);

$smallArr = min($a, $b);
$largeArr = max($a, $b);

$smallCount = count($smallArr);
$largeCount = count($largeArr);

for ($i=0; $i < $largeCount; $i++) { 
    $result[] = $smallArr[$i % $smallCount] * $largeArr[$i];
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 10
    [1] => 40
    [2] => 30
)
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/139411)

Comment: Aha, but what if `$a` has less elements than `$b`? :)

Comment: @Jack: What's the expected result in that case? For example: `$a = [10, 20]; $b = [1, 2, 3]; $c = array_mult($a, $b);`  will produce: `[10, 40]`. [**See demo**](https://eval.in/139410). In any case, it should be easy enough to add a check like so: `if ($aCount >= $bCount) { ... }`.

Comment: This is of course somewhat speculative, but it's my understanding that the answer in that case should be `[10, 40, 30]`, as in the smallest array gets repeated.

Comment: @Jack: Reading the question again, your comment makes sense. Answer's been updated to handle this case :-)

Answer (score 0):

first have `$b` of the same length than `$a` :

```
$i=0;
while(count($b) < count($a)){
    if($i > count($b){$i=0;}
    $b[] = $b[$i];
    $i++;
}
```

Then multiply both arrays :

```
$total = array_map(function($x, $y) { return $x * $y; }, $a, $b);
```

`$total` contains what you want.

Comment: It's not entirely clear from the question, but what if `$a` is the smaller array of the two? :)

Answer (score 0):

Throwing in a `MultipleIterator` solution (requires >= 5.5):

```
$a = array(10, 20, 30, 40, 50);
$b = array(1, 2, 3);

$m = new MultipleIterator(MultipleIterator::MIT_KEYS_ASSOC);
$m->attachIterator(new InfiniteIterator(new ArrayIterator($a)), 'a');
$m->attachIterator(new InfiniteIterator(new ArrayIterator($b)), 'b');

$c = array();

foreach (new LimitIterator($m, 0, max(count($a), count($b))) as $both) {
        $c[] = $both['a'] * $both['b'];
}

print_r($c);
```

I'm using the [`InfiniteIterator`](http://php.net/infiniteiterator) to repeat the inner iterator as many times as is necessary; both iterators are then attached to the [`MultipleIterator`](http://php.net/multipleiterator) that will simultaneously iterate over both inner iterators. It's effectively another `InfiniteIterator`, so it needs to be limited.

Finally, the [`LimitIterator`](http://php.net/limititerator) will iterate over its inner iterator `max(count($a), count($b))` times, the size of the biggest array.